# Increasing clickable area of an edge in D3 diagram

Tags: svg, d3.js, dagre-d3

I have a graph being made by d3, with dagre-d3 sitting on top of it for drawing directed graphs. This gives me what I expect for rendering the graph:

[image]

To edit the data building the graph, each element is click-able. This is fine for the cases where the edges are rendered with labels, but they don't always have labels, leading to the unlabeled edges being very hard to click to edit. These style assigned to the edges is:

```
#visitGraph .edgePath {
   cursor: pointer;
   stroke: #333;
   stroke-width: 2px;
   fill: none;
   padding: 10px;
}
```

The rendered svg is:

```
<g class="edgePath enter">
    <path marker-end="url(#arrowhead)" d="M198.5,121L198,124.9C198.4,128.8,198.4,136.6,198.4,144.5C198.4,152.3,198.4,160.1,198.4,164.0L198.5,168" style="opacity: 1">
    </path>
</g>
```

Without changing the code in dagre-d3 to add over-drawing on the lines, like I've seen in other SVG suggestions, what can I do to increase the area around these elements that are clickable? I've already attempted `padding`, `margin`, and various values for `pointer-events` in the style to no avail.

Comment: You could increase the stroke width. This will make the lines wider though.

Comment: I tried that, but by the time the edges are easily clickable, it looks quite ugly.

Comment: The only alternative I can see would be to have some kind of dummy element that is invisible, but bigger handle the clicks.

Comment: If I see no other suggestions, I'll probably make a patch for dagre and do a pull request. I can't imagine I'll be the only one using that library and needing this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it, I'm pretty sure it'd work with `path` as well.

```
<g>
  <line class="clickable-area" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="5" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1"></line>
  <line class="visible-edge" stroke="red" stroke-width="0.5" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1"></line>
</g>
```

As you can see, there's a dummy edge with a larger `stroke-width` value and I put the original edge on that element.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `<path>` element has no `fill`. Could you change `fill: none` to `fill: white` or `fill: transparent` to make the entire area clickable?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the labels to make it easier to click on. I used font awesome to make it a little more fancy.

```js
g.setEdge(node1.uuid, node2.uuid, {
  labelType: "html",
  label: "<span class='fa fa-2x fa-info-circle'/>",
  style: getStyleForEdge(node1, node2),
  arrowheadStyle: getArrowForStyle(node1,node2)
});
```

```js
//inner is the graph element
inner.selectAll("g.edgeLabel").on("click", function(id) {
   selectEdge(id);
});
```